# How to assign the contents of two arrays in yasm and calculate the result based on the following equation

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64, yasm

I'm a beginner to assembly language. Can you guys help me to guide the steps to complete this assignment?
The equation is : Sigma notation, for i = 0 to N-1 ((-3 +a(i)) +(b(i) -14))
[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiJZP.png)

The task in the main section is to explicitly follow the equation and iteratively add -3 to the indexed value in array a, subtract the indexed value in array b by 14 and finally add
these two parts and store the resulting value in memory location result.

Use a maximum of three general purpose registers in this lab. NOT allowed to change any values in the memory locations of aand b. Some of the opcodes of use in this lab are:

•mov - moving data from register-register, register-variable etc

•lea - loading effective address of a variable to a register.

•add - adding two values in registers or in variables.

•sub - subtract two values in registers or in variables

Upon completion of the task, zero out all the used registers and return.

I got the segment.data

```
       segment .data
a      dw    -4, 22, 144   ; array of 3 values
b      db    -3, -16, 12   ; array of 3 values
result dq    0              ; memory to result
       segment .text
       global main
main:
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you guys help me to guide the steps to complete this assignment?

First, I would write out a proper C version of that, so you can see the detail that has to be written out in programming languages, but hidden by the Sigma notation.  It will only be about 3 lines of code in total, and that will add clarity.

Next, fundamentally, the approach is to decompose the problem (i.e. that C code), into smaller piece parts, then solve each piece part, and recompose that into a total solution.

It is good to start with is understanding the data first; here variables `i`, `N`, `result`, `a`, `b` and possibly a temporary or two if you need to compute an intermediate value.  That's more than 3 items so, they cannot all go in registers.  However global variables can be accessed without requiring registers (`a`, `b`, and `result` are global variables).

Next write out the code and solve each statement, and solve each expression in each statement.  Once you know where your variables are you can write instructions that work with them.

The idea is to first map the variables of the algorithm into physical storage of the processor: either CPU registers or memory.  Once you have that mapping, you can start to write assembly instructions, but the other way around is awkward (though you may have to iterate if you run out of registers mid way, for example).

For example, the basic for-loop can be translated to a while loop, then to an if-goto-label loop.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    <loop-body>
```

---

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < N ) {
    <loop-body>
    i++;
}
```

---

```
    int i = 0;
loop1:
    if ( i >= N ) goto endLoop1;
    <loop-body>
    i++;
    goto loop1;
endLoop1:
```

---

The above if-goto-label form is pretty close to assembly, and has the control structure of the original for-loop.

Next, break down the loop-body into its individual piece parts, which will include array referencing, addition, subtraction, and summation.  So, figure out each of those and then place them together in context of the formula you're working.

Compose all of that into a solution and you'll have your program.  If you find you run out of registers, given a working limit of 3, you can take a step back and figure out something to put in memory instead.